# Are there general css paths for drupal

Tags: theming

Is there a specific drupal way to focus on one specific part of a nodes element in the css path? For example if I change the H2 element within my theme css it changes all H2... How can I change one specific one on the page. The object is to be able to focus on particular elements to make them unique... If this is possible how do I write the style declarations?

Comment: Your node should have a class on it.

Comment: my nodes have classes... What I am referring to is the css declaration path... it looks somewhat like this in drupal ---- html body.question-page div.container div#content div div#mainbar div#question.question table tbody tr td div#comments-48081.comments table tfoot tr td.comment-form form#add-comment-48081 table tbody tr td input -----

Comment: I am asking for general practice on focusing on one element to be able to change that one element in my css... hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal allows your site to have many [Themes](http://drupal.org/project/themes) installed. Themes can define their own HTML structure to make your site look a certain way. Drupal has a few themes the ship out-of-the-box.

Depending on the theme you use it may or may not contain HTML `class`es or `id`s in the source to easily target specific items on the page. Typically, themes and Core html is fairly darn flexible.

Looking at the [Zen Theme](http://www.drupal.org/project/zen) HTML and CSS markup you can see it has fairly specific rules to get at and theme alot of the content from Zen and also core drupal themes: [Useful CSS selectors to add to your stylesheets](http://drupal.org/node/1707736)